# Trying to find the selected value and contents in a div to add a class

Tags: jquery, select

When the page loads with the select dropdown I need the value to show/hide results (or add a class). I have the results working on change but not on page load. Currently all results show when the page loads and I would like only the results with the state of "AL" to show on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
      if ( ($('.broker-chosen select option:selected').val()=='AL') && (!$(".broker-locations_state:not(:contains('AL'))") ) ) { 
          $(".broker-results").addClass("chosen-results_wonky");
       }
});
```

```css
.chosen-results_wonky { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="broker-chosen">
<select><option selected="" value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option></select>
</div>

<div class="broker-results row"><div class="broker-locations_state">AR</div> </div>

<div class="broker-results row"><div class="broker-locations_state">AL</div> </div>
```

Comment: you say that it works when the `change` event occurs. so you only have to trigger a `change` event right after setting the event handler.. `$(..).on('change',...).trigger('change')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a `change` event handler set-up that works correctly, just trigger a `change` event and your existing code should handle it.

Have a look at the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    const selection = this.value;
    const allLocations = $('.broker-results').addClass('chosen-results_wonky');
    allLocations.filter(function() {
      return $('.broker-locations_state',this).text() === selection;
    }).removeClass('chosen-results_wonky');
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.chosen-results_wonky {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="broker-chosen">
  <select>
    <option selected="" value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="broker-results row">
  <div class="broker-locations_state">AR</div>
</div>

<div class="broker-results row">
  <div class="broker-locations_state">AL</div>
</div>
```